# how to post Guzzle 6 Async data

Tags: php, yii2, guzzle

i trying to post data as Async with using Guzzle 6(latest ver)

```
    $client = new Client();
    $request = $client->postAsync($url, [
        'json' => [
                'company_name' => 'update Name'
        ],
    ]);
```

but i am not getting any request form Guzzle like post request on terminal

Answer (score 6):

Because it's a `promise,` you need to put `then`

and the promise will not called unless you put `$promise->wait()`

This is a simple post request using `postAsync` based on your question:

```
$client = new Client();
$promise = $client->postAsync($url, [
    'json' => [
            'company_name' => 'update Name'
    ],
])->then(
    function (ResponseInterface $res){
        $response = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents());

        return $response;
    },
    function (RequestException $e) {
        $response = [];
        $response->data = $e->getMessage();

        return $response;
    }
);
$response = $promise->wait();
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to send the request?

http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html?highlight=async

```
$client = new Client();
$request = new Request('POST', $url, [
    "json" => [
        'company_name' => 'update Name']
    ]);

$promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
});
$promise->wait();
```

Answer (score 3):

Guzzle 6 has very little practical examples/documentation for developers to refer. I am sharing an example on how to use postAsync and Pool object. This allows concurrent async requests using guzzle 6. ( I was not able to find a direct example and spent 2 days to get working code )

```
function postInBulk($inputs)
{
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://a.b.com'
    ]);
    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer token_from_directus_user'
    ];

    $requests = function ($a) use ($client, $headers) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
            yield function() use ($client, $headers) {
                return $client->postAsync('https://a.com/project/items/collection', [
                    'headers' => $headers,
                    'json' => [
                        "snippet" => "snippet",
                        "rank" => "1",
                        "status" => "published"
                    ]        
                ]);
            };
        }
        
    };

    $pool = new Pool($client, $requests($inputs),[
        'concurrency' => 5,
        'fulfilled' => function (Response $response, $index) {
            // this is delivered each successful response
        },
        'rejected' => function (RequestException $reason, $index) {
            // this is delivered each failed request
        },
    ]);

    $pool->promise()->wait();
}
```

Comment: this answer may need correction as when I used the $requests block it gave me a single request but my requirement was to get 5 requests.

Answer (score 1):

most likely you'll need to call `wait();`

`$request->wait();`